# Keras: loss fluctuates between inf and number

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision, numerical-stability

I am working on a Keras model with a custom loss function provided by a [Mixture Density Network final layer](https://github.com/omimo/Keras-MDN) (the loss tries to minimize the negative log likelihood of some Gaussian models).

What confuses me is the loss will sometimes hit an epoch in which it returns -inf as the resulting loss. Then the next iteration the loss will be a number again (e.g. -2.1). The loss sometimes bounces between negative infinity and a number every other epoch.

The negative loss is evidently to be expected with a NLL loss, but this fluctuation is confusing to me. What explains this behavior within Keras? My understanding is the -inf loss is caused by numeric underflow somewhere, but I'm not sure how the model can recover from this and re-establish numeric stability thereafter.

Does anyone know how this works? I'd be very grateful for any suggestions others can offer on this question.

Comment: Did you try it with lower learning rate? This type of fluctuations often are because of the too high learning rate.

Comment: Yes, but my learning rate is now 0.000001 -- is that reasonable for a learning rate? Simpler (smaller) models I've built for trivial tasks have been able to use much larger learning rates. Is 0.000001 a reasonable lr?

Comment: It highly depends on the loss function, but not too frequent I guess.